# Python: Create a dataframe with pairs and count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and I have a big dataframe. Want to count the pairs of column elements appearing in the dataframe:

### Sample code

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

data = {'compound': ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d','d','e','e','e','e'],
        'element': ['carbon','nitrogen','oxygen','hydrogen','nitrogen','nitrogen','oxygen','nitrogen','oxygen','carbon','carbon','nitrogen','oxygen','hydrogen']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['compound', 'element'])
pair = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df['element'].unique() , df['element'].unique() )))
pair.columns = ['element1', 'element2']
pair=pair[pair['element1']!=pair['element2']]
```

I want to create count of each pair i.e.

```
count = []
for index,row in pair.iterrows():
    df1 = df[df['element']==row['element1']]
    df2 = df[df['element']==row['element2']]
    df_merg = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='compound')
    count.append(len(df_merg.index))
    
pair['count'] = count
```

### Problem 1

This does not work on a **df** of 2.8 million rows (or is very slow), Can you somebody please suggest an efficient method?

### Problem 2

The pair creates duplicates due to product i.e. ['carbon','nitrogen'] as well as ['nitrogen','carbon'] are part of **pair**. Can I somehow have *unique* combinations?

### Problem 3

The final dataframe **'pair'** has indexes messed up. I am new to python and havent used `.iloc` much. What am I missing? e.g.

[Image for row number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f32n0.png)

Comment: Please post your expected output?

Comment: Pandas is slow for larger datasets. Because by default, Pandas executes its functions as a single process using a single CPU core. You can use modin to speed up and scale up your pandas. Modin under the hood uses Ray (A fast and simple framework for building and running distributed applications.). More details [here](https://github.com/modin-project/modin).

Comment: @MayankPorwal: I am new to this, so reduced privileges due to low rep. However I have shared a screenshot of my present results in the imgur link. As the problem statement clearly explains that I want to make it efficient - as the same code is not working on a big dataset thus expected results are already in the code and question.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

I think this can be better done with dicts instead of dataframes. I first convert the input dataframe into a dict so we can use it easily without having to subset repeatedly (which would be slow). This should help with Problem 1.

Problem 2 can be solved by using `itertools.combinations`, as shown below. Problem 3 doesn't happen in my proposed solution. For your solution, you can solve problem 3 by resetting the index (assuming index is not useful) like so: `pair.reset_index(drop=True)`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools
data = {'compound': ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d','d','e','e','e','e'],
        'element': ['carbon','nitrogen','oxygen','hydrogen','nitrogen','nitrogen','oxygen','nitrogen','oxygen','carbon','carbon','nitrogen','oxygen','hydrogen']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['compound', 'element'])

# If these are real compounds and elements, each value in the following
# dict should be small because there are only 118 elements (more are
# hypothesized but not yet made). Even if there are a large number of
# compounds, storing them as a dict should not be too different from storing
# them in a dataframe that has repeated compound names.
compound_to_elements = {
    compound: set(subset['element'])
    for compound, subset in df.groupby(by=['compound'])
}

# Generate combinations that ignore order
combos = list(itertools.combinations(list(set(df['element'])), 2))
counts = [0] * len(combos)

# For each element pair, find out how many distinct compounds does it belong to.
# The looping order can be switched depending upon whether there are more 
# compounds or more 2-element combinations.
for _, elements in compound_to_elements.items():
    for i, (element1, element2) in enumerate(combos):
        if (element1 in elements) and (element2 in elements):
            counts[i] += 1

pairs = pd.DataFrame.from_records(combos, columns=['element1', 'element2'])
pairs['count'] = counts
#    element1  element2  count
# 0  nitrogen  hydrogen      2
# 1  nitrogen    oxygen      4
# 2  nitrogen    carbon      3
# 3  hydrogen    oxygen      1
# 4  hydrogen    carbon      1
# 5    oxygen    carbon      3
```

**Alternative Solution.**
The solution above has room for improvement because we checked whether or not an element is a part of a compound multiple times (for example, we check "nitrogen" is a part of "a" multiple times -- once for each combination). The following alternative solution improves upon the previous solution by removing such an inefficiency. Which solution is feasible or faster would depend a little bit on your exact data and available memory.

```py
# If these are real compounds and elements, then the number of keys in
# the following dict should be small because there are only 118 elements
# (more are hypothesized but not yet made). But, some values may be big
# sets of compounds (such as for Carbon).
element_to_compounds = {
    element: set(subset['compound'])
    for element, subset in df.groupby(by=['element'])
}

# Generate combinations that ignore order
combos = list(itertools.combinations(list(set(df['element'])), 2))
counts = [
    len(element_to_compounds[element1]
        .intersection(element_to_compounds[element2]))
    for (element1, element2) in combos
]

pairs = pd.DataFrame.from_records(combos, columns=['element1', 'element2'])
pairs['count'] = counts
#    element1  element2  count
# 0  nitrogen  hydrogen      2
# 1  nitrogen    oxygen      4
# 2  nitrogen    carbon      3
# 3  hydrogen    oxygen      1
# 4  hydrogen    carbon      1
# 5    oxygen    carbon      3
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code and explanations. However I still face the issue that the code runs successfully on a smaller dataset however, for a larger one it gets stuck. No, the original dataset is not of elements - it is of FMCG products and their attrubutes (e.g. ingredients, flavours) etc. I have unique list of ~1.4 k attributes which I want to pair up and count the no. of products having the said pair. - this is for a networkx experiment and I am creating an 'edge' dataset.

Comment: If the actual data is not of real chemicals and elements, then the rough size assumptions I made above are not valid. Maybe try out modin (as suggested in the comments) or a distributed dataframe tool on a cluster such as spark or dask.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

data = {'compound': ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d','d','e','e','e','e'],
        'element': ['carbon','nitrogen','oxygen','hydrogen','nitrogen','nitrogen','oxygen','nitrogen','oxygen','carbon','carbon','nitrogen','oxygen','hydrogen']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['compound', 'element'])
pair = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df['element'].unique() , df['element'].unique() )))
pair.columns = ['element1', 'element2']
pair=pair[pair['element1']!=pair['element2']]

## create a tuple of names
## sort the values in combined column if order doesn't matter to you
pair["combined"] = tuple(zip(pair.element1, pair.element2))
pair.groupby("combined").size().reset_index(name= "count")
```